# PHP : how to use mysql prepare statement inside single quote

Tags: php, mysql

In My PHP project I want to make prepare statement to insert point.
I did it as fallows

```
$query = "update d_location set dl_location = GeomFromText('POINT(:lat :lon)') where dl_id = :id";
            echo $query;
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $params = array(
                        'lat'=>$lat,
                        'lon'=>$lon,
                        'id'=>$d_id
                    );
            $stmt->execute($params);
```

but it shows following error message

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

What is the problem here? dl_location datatype is GEOMETRY

Comment: Do you use `mysqli` or `PDO`? Does `execute`  for your method  really take parameters? (For `mysqli` I think you need to use `bind_param`)

Comment: I used PDO.this $stmt->execute($params) works for other queries

Comment: You need a seperator for this `:lat :lon` Have you tried `:lat, :lon`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gis-point-property-functions.html says `SELECT X(POINT(56.7, 53.34));` - Try removing the quotes in `('POINT(:lat :lon)')` also. They most likely shouldn't be in there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- wouldn't that be a syntax error then. Or is this one of the situations where mysql is presenting a _wrong_ / _misleading_ error message?

Comment: @t.niese Hard to say. The manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gis-point-property-functions.html states `SELECT X(POINT(56.7, 53.34));` where the two points are seperated by a comma. The OP's code doesn't have it. My guess is the quotes in `('POINT(:lat :lon)')` that could play a role here.

Comment: Try removing the quotes and adding a comma `(POINT(:lat, :lon))` - If that still doesn't work, then it won't let you bind it that way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I remove quotes and adding a comma,it save null in database

Comment: this parameter binding method work for other queries

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Plus, what is `GeomFromText`, a row?

Comment: thank you @Fred-ii- Its not a row.now it work...I update Answer.Thank you

Comment: I see you posted an answer. That was going to be my next suggestion to assign variables instead. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It work like this.

```
$location = 'POINT(' . $lat . " " . $lon . ')';
            $query = "update d_location set dl_location = GeomFromText(:location) where dl_id = :id";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $params = array(
                        'location'=>$location,
                        'id'=>$d_id
                    );
            $stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.